# Where do I change my password and email for my account?

Tags: support

I need to change my password and email for this account. I think used openid to create this account. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged-in, and look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/1352, you will see a *change password* under *Stack Exchange*. That is the last login method you used on Drupal Answers.